# NPE on LinkedList implementation, but I created the objects?

Tags: java, list, pointers, exception, null

When main runs, the null pointer exception occurs at:

`stringList.add("Test");`

and specifically on this line of JAList in the add function:

```
dummy.getNextNode().setNodePrev(node);
```

I don't understand because at that point, `dummy` is initialized,  `dummy.getNextNode()` is dummy, and `node` is initialized just before.

My only thought is that the constructor isn't setting the values properly when I call the constructor for JAList?

```
JAList<String> stringList = new JAList<String>();
```

As a side note, why don't you need the < E > when you create the constructor?

JANode.java:

```
public class JANode<E> {

private E value;
private JANode<E> next;
private JANode<E> prev;

public JANode(E value, JANode<E> next, JANode<E> prev)
{   
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;       
}

public E getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setNodeNext(JANode<E> next)
{
    this.next = next;
}

public JANode<E> getNextNode()
{
    return next;
}

public JANode<E> getPrevNode()
{
    return prev;
}

public void setNodePrev(JANode<E> prev)
{
    this.prev = prev;
}

}
```

JAList.java:

```
  public class JAList<E> {


    private int initialCapacity;
    private JANode<E> dummy;

    public JAList()
    {
        this.initialCapacity= 10;
        this.dummy = new JANode<E>(null, dummy, dummy);
    }

    public JAList(int initialCapacity)
    {
        this.initialCapacity = initialCapacity;
        this.dummy = new JANode<E>(null, dummy, dummy);
    }

    public E add(E e)
    {
        JANode<E> node = new JANode<E>(e, dummy, dummy);

        node.setNodeNext(dummy.getNextNode());
        dummy.getNextNode().setNodePrev(node);
        dummy.setNodeNext(node);
        node.setNodePrev(dummy);
        return e;
    }

    public JANode<E> getNode(E value)
    {
        JANode<E> local = dummy.getNextNode();

        while (local != dummy && local.getValue() != value)
        {
         local = local.getNextNode();
        }   

        return local;

    }

}
```

main.java:

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JAList<String> stringList = new JAList<String>();
        stringList.add("Test");
        stringList.add("B");
        stringList.add("C");

        System.out.println(stringList.getNode("Test").getValue());      
        System.out.println(stringList.getNode("Test").getNextNode().getValue());

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** At the moment of calling the constructor of `JAList<E>`, this line

```
this.dummy = new JANode<E>(null, dummy, dummy);
```

is the same that executing this:

```
this.dummy = new JANode<E>(null, null, null);
```

because you're using `dummy` as parameter but Java will initialize its value with `null` by default. Thus, when you later execute:

```
dummy.getNextNode().setNodePrev(node);
```

This part: `dummy.getNextNode()` returns `null` and it throws an NPE.

**Solution:** Change your code in the constructor to something like this:

```
this.dummy = null;
```

And in your `add` method, validate that is the current list is empty by evaluating if `this.dummy` is `null`:

```
public E add(E e) {
    JANode<E> node = new JANode<E>(e, dummy, dummy);
    if (dummy == null) {
        dummy = node;
    } else {
        //your code for add goes here...
        //note: it has errors as well...
        //...
    }
    return e;
}
```

Comment: I made the change to the constructors in JAList and added the if/else. I'm still getting a null pointer exception on the same line in add after recompilation, except it now throws the exception on stringList.add("B"); I think it when it tries to add the first string, it assigns node to dummy and returns, and then on the second string the same problem is recurring, because at the time I created the object JANode<E> node, dummy was still null. Isn't there a value I can use instead of null that would be compatible with E and not trigger an exception?